# Enabling CORS in Create React App utility

Tags: express, cors, create-react-app

I need to use **CORS** node module in React created using `create-react-app` utility.

Since its a utility I am not able to tweak inside and inject **CORS** into preconfigured **EXPRESS** module.

How can we achieve this?

Comment: you have to use this plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: I knew that, but I am unable to integrate it with **create-react-app** :-(

Comment: @challenger you don't have to use that. See my answer below.

Comment: CORS: Cross-Origin Resource sharing,If which means, we can't access resources on ABC, com from XYZ.com.                                                                                                        Solution : For CORS issue fix needs to apply on server not on client side

Answer (score 33):

If you are needing this for development and wanting to access an api from your react app but getting an error like this-

```
Failed to load http://localhost:8180/tables: 
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:8180'
that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is
therefore not allowed access. Have the server send the header with a valid
value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to
'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

then you can get the create-react-app server to proxy your request to your api server quite easily.

create-react-app uses the webpack development server to serve your react app.

So if your react app is being served from `http://localhost:3000` and the api you want to connect to is at `http://localhost:8180/tables` you can simply add a `proxy` value into your react app's package.json file like this-

```
proxy: "http://localhost:8180",
```

then from your react app call your api like

```
fetch('/tables').then(....)
```

the request will be sent to the create-react-app server which will send it on to the api server and return the results for you.

Full details here [Proxying API Requests in Development](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the link has changed. New one is : https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development

Comment: What about if the api is hosted in another domain? This seems like for the same domain

Comment: @IanSmith Where did this answer go?

Comment: @EnricoBorba I was wrong and deleted my answer, I thought you could utilize the hosts file and spoof a domain to localhost..

Comment: @samayo See [the linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64641435/1705829) point 6 for CORS in another domain. Just use the other domain: `"proxy":"http://my-domain"`

Answer (score 12):

**SIMPLER SOLUTION IS:**

Because the server from `create-react-app` is only used during `development`, then you can use additional *extensions* on each *browser* to resolve the issue. Here are some *extensions* that you can use to solve **CORS** problems during `development` stage:

- [Extension for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en)
- [Extension for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/)
- [Extension for Opera](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/cors-toggle/)

There is Whitelist features that can use to activated the extension in only specified websites. So don't worry about the security.

> Of course, at the `production` stage you can solve **CORS** problems on your respective *server*, so at this stage, the *browser extension* is no longer needed.

Comment: Wouldn't using these extensions be deemed unsafe since you disable CORS for all websites then?

Comment: @ReturnOfTheMac there is a whitelist feature that you can use, so that the extension only runs on some of the sites listed.

Comment: It says, ** When CORS is allowed in your browser, for the following domains, CORS is disabled. ** means, only listed domains get blocked.

Answer (score 1):

CORS: Cross-Origin Resource sharing, which means, we can't access resources on ABC.com from XYZ.com.

Solution: For the CORS issue **fix needs to apply on the server** not on the client side

ABC.com needs to allow XYZ.com to access resources.

Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58451189/6942012

Answer (score 1):

When cors issue is encountered in create-react-app all you need to do is set the proxy key in the package.json file.
The proxy is pointed to the endpoint you want to interact with,note proxy doesn't work in production you have to explicitly set an endpoint to interact with.

For more checkout: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development

```js
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-query": "^3.39.2",
    "react-router": "^6.3.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```