# i have some problem for cross origin on reactJS " Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. "

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm making a web application using reactjs, and when development is suddenly this error appears. "Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development."

I still haven't tried anything. but I have undo the function that I created with ctrl + z. but this error still appears.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable CORS in create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47902840/enable-cors-in-create-react-app)

Comment: please add your tried code, might be problem with your function call. try to call in compoDidMount()

Comment: I don't know what code to put here, because this error suddenly appeared when I was making a login session with localstorage on reactJS

Comment: you cant make req to different domain like `:4200` making req to `:8000`

Comment: Btw, This problem was solved when I remove all folder node_modules. Back to normal again.