# how can i solve the problem CORS policy on react js

Tags: reactjs

from origin 'http://localhost:3003' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

when i post request using the other domain serves how i solve the problem!!

Comment: What is backend written in

Comment: on backend i use nodejs and i just use it to make api to database how i solve this issue :( any help!

Comment: I have provided a link to more other solutions please follow it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this post still on stackoverflow i believe it will help

[How to allow CORS in react.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46337471/how-to-allow-cors-in-react-js)

Answer (score 1):

For development you can use proxy to `localhost:3003`. Write this line in package.json of react project. `"proxy": "http://localhost:3003"`.

To solve this issue, you will have to do in backend, for example if you backend is in nodejs then you can use [CORS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) package.

Install cors package.

```bash
npm i cors
```

and then in your nodejs file write this

```
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors())
```

To configure `cors` you can refer [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuring-cors)

Comment: my backend it is just api using node js how i solve this problem :(

Comment: I have updated the answer. Now check is this helps or not. @gemma

Comment: i add in my node js cors

Comment: does it worked? @gemma

Comment: no it doen't work

Comment: @gemma can you show me your code?

Comment: The problem from api and that was from header setting on cors

Answer (score -1):

I installed the cors unblock extension in Google Chrome and no more problems to me.

Comment: i want to upload my project website who to solve this issue!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

in your node.js backend add:

```
app.use(cors({origin: true, credentials: true}));
```

also you can try installing [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en) chrome extension. it fixed the issue for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).