# Can't get token from server using fetch or axios

Tags: reactjs, agora.io

I'm using ReactJs to build a video call app.
I also up agora-token-service into railway. Testing is oke. But when i try to fetch data, it's has a ploblem, I also tried to fix it but it didn't work. mode: 'no-cors also didn't work

[image]

i need a solution please!

Answer (score 0):

You are using **http** and trying to access content from **https** thats way it's giving this error.

try to host this website or you can use temporary service like [ngrok](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrok)

use `npm i ngrok`

Answer (score 0):

See enabling CORS references below, hope this helps.

[How to allow CORS in react.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46337471/how-to-allow-cors-in-react-js)

```
It is better to add CORS enabling code on Server Side. To enable CORS in NodeJS and ExpressJs based application following code should be included-

var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

```
In response, the server returns a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header with Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, which means that the resource can be accessed by any origin.

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
This pattern of the Origin and Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers is the simplest use of the access control protocol. If the resource owners at https://bar.other wished to restrict access to the resource to requests only from https://foo.example (i.e., no domain other than https://foo.example can access the resource in a cross-origin manner), they would send:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://foo.example
Note: When responding to a credentialed requests request, the server must specify an origin in the value of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, instead of specifying the "*" wildcard.
```