# Expecting UserSignup to lead to Log in view - leads to whitescreen, No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: reactjs, axios, django-allauth

## The user sign up submit button is expected to lead to log in page

if successful this would to redirect to http://localhost:3000/signin. the setup is React.js on the front end, react is installed with npm and currently working.

Instead, after user sign up, submit button leads to this error message

- whitescreen with [console log error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ist3.png).
- The url stays in http://localhost:3000/signup
- The error message that appears on startup suggests there is an issue with CORS.

---

## debugging steps - CORS currently is problem area

1. Reviewed the Console Log Error Message alongside the correponding handlesubmit function on line 38-46. I have since ruled it out or at least identified that CORS needs be fixed first. I have reduced the full code and error message on this post to just external hyperlinks jso as to avoid misleading or confusing the reader.

- [full error log screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ist3.png)

2. review of Console Log Error Message on page load

```
signup:1
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://trick-or-treat-drf-api-09114a4f424d.herokuapp.com/dj-rest-auth/registratio
n/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't
pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

3. I have tried `npm install cors`
   installs successfully, however same CORS error message is apparent.
4. I have tried adding CORS Middleware to src/app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
```

just leads to whitescreen, although does remove CORS error message.

instead, first error message becomes `response.js:43  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')`

full message below

```
log.js:24 [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
response.js:43  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
    at Object.<anonymous> (response.js:43:1)
    at ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js (response.js:1169:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:856:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js (express.js:22:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:856:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at ./node_modules/express/index.js (index.js:11:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:856:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at Module.<anonymous> (App.js:17:1)
    at ./src/App.js (App.js:68:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:856:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at Module.<anonymous> (index.css:82:1)
    at ./src/index.js (index.js:24:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:856:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at 1 (utils.js:18:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:856:1)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45:1)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32:1)
    at main.chunk.js:1:71
(anonymous) @ response.js:43
./node_modules/express/lib/response.js @ response.js:1169
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:856
fn @ bootstrap:150
./node_modules/express/lib/express.js @ express.js:22
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:856
fn @ bootstrap:150
./node_modules/express/index.js @ index.js:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:856
fn @ bootstrap:150
(anonymous) @ App.js:17
./src/App.js @ App.js:68
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:856
fn @ bootstrap:150
(anonymous) @ index.css:82
./src/index.js @ index.js:24
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:856
fn @ bootstrap:150
1 @ utils.js:18
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:856
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.chunk.js:1
```

5. Putting whole middleware inside function

error message claims express is not a function.

```
Uncaught TypeError: express is not a function
[...]
```

6. I have tried putting `app.use(cors());` inside `App()` function, while leaving constants outside below the imports.

whitescreen stays along with error message

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
```

it appears express.js needs to be installed to recognise the express function.

7. install express.js framework in terminal as per documentation `npm install express --save`

now try steps 4,5,6 again... all lead to same error messages

8. reverted step 4 to 7 (express.js is not likely to help). There is no django project, so investigating how to enable CORS via django. Installed django-admin startproject corstest. adding     "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware" to MIDDLEWARE and "corsheaders" to INSTALLED APPS to include CORS as per the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/). Same error message at top appearing.
9. Tried CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True to settings.py. Same issue and error message as step 8.
10. Reviewed how React connects to django API

```
    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      try {
        // This is where the API call to the Django backend happens
        await axios.post("/dj-rest-auth/registration/", signUpData);
        // After a successful sign-up, redirects the user to the sign-in page
        history.push("/signin");
      } catch (err) {
        // If there's an error, capture it in the state to be displayed
        setErrors(err.response?.data);
      }
    };
```

11. Tried using python3 manage.py runserver but leads to this error message

```
[...long traceback...]
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'corstest.settings'
```

12. same error message from using `python manage.py startapp corstestapp`. the remaining issue is to correctly successfully integrate the newly installed django project which has django-cors-headers package installed to React, in the hope that
13. inspecting the newly installed corstest/manage.py I have seen the error message in lines 7-9.

```
def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'corstest.settings')
[...]
```

---

Links:

- repo here: [src/pages/auth/signupform.js](https://github.com/lmcrean/halloween-hackathon-Laurie2/blob/main/src/pages/auth/SignUpForm.js)*

---

Further Reading:

- “Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).” MDN Web Docs, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS. Accessed 30 Nov. 2023.
  -“Access-Control-Allow-Origin.” MDN Web Docs, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Accessed 12 Dec. 2023.
- “How to Allow CORS in React.Js?” Stack Overflow, [How to allow CORS in react.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46337471/how-to-allow-cors-in-react-js). Accessed 29 Nov. 2023.
- “React CORS Guide: What It Is and How to Enable It.” StackHawk, https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/react-cors-guide-what-it-is-and-how-to-enable-it/. Accessed 29 Nov. 2023.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is outlined clearly in the first error message in the [first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ist3.png). Your server does not have CORS HTTP headers configured to allow requests from localhost, so the browser is blocking the response from being read by the application.

The rest of the issue like the other errors and the white screen is due to missing error handling for when this network request fails due to CORS (you can't even parse the response so `err.response?.data` won't exist).

If you were deploying in production and the React app was on the same host as the API, this error would not occur. CORS is kicking it because you are hitting it from your local dev server.

The server needs to be modified to correctly configure the CORS headers on the API endpoints to allow localhost. I won't regurgitate that here as a wealth of info is available on the web on what these headers are and how to add them for various different server technologies. For you it looks like you could just use [django-cors-headers](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/).

If you really want to, in a pinch, you could instead run Chrome with the `--disable-web-security` flag. Obviously only makes sense in dev scenarios.