# Dealing with CORS in a create react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors

I am in production and I run into a `CORS` error when fetching data from my Payment Platform with the following error

> Failed to load https://www.pesapal.com/api/QueryPaymentDetails?oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1513397234&pesapal_merchant_reference=JUB-1513395508&pesapal_transaction_tracking_id=2cb419c1-bdc8-43d7-b573-d2cffd199a82: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://tiip.co.tz' is therefore not allowed access.`

How can I deal resolve this in Production for a `REACTJS` application created through create-react-app

Comment: Possible duplicate of 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43462367/how-to-overcome-the-cors-issue-in-reactjs

Comment: This API should be used by a server, query from a browser would have the CORS issue. As long as the API provider doesn't allow your web app calling it you have no choice but to do a proxy API yourself.

Comment: Thanks Gentlemen, I have to move the API call to the server