# PUT request doesn't work on Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, axios, put

I want to update the data of the row of my table developed with **Node.js** on the backend, **React** on frontend and **MySQL** about the database.

**My Edit class:**

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    clients: [],
    Prenom: '',
    Nom: '',
    FAX: '',
    Telephone: '',
    Email: '',
    Adresse1: '',
    Adresse2: '',
    Code: props.match.params.Code
  }
  // this.logChange = this.logChange.bind(this);
  this.handleEdit = this.handleEdit.bind(this);
}
handleEdit(event) {
  //Edit functionality
  //event.preventDefault()
  var client = {
    Prenom: this.state.Prenom,
    Nom: this.state.Nom,
    FAX: this.state.FAX,
    Telephone: this.state.Telephone,
    Email: this.state.Email,
    Adresse1: this.state.Adresse1,
    Adresse2: this.state.Adresse2
  }
  axios({
    method: 'put',
    url: "http://localhost:4000/app/editclient/" + this.props.match.params.Code,
    data: client,
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Accept": "application/json",
    }
  }).then(function(response) { // empty form
    this.setState({
      Code: ""
    });
    this.setState({
      Prenom: ""
    });
    this.setState({
      Nom: ""
    });
    this.setState({
      FAX: ""
    });
    this.setState({
      Telephone: ""
    });
    this.setState({
      Email: ""
    });
    this.setState({
      Adresse1: ""
    });
    this.setState({
      Adresse2: ""
    });
  }.bind(this)).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
  event.preventDefault();
}
<Button type="submit" color="success" onClick={(event) => this. handleEdit(event)} >Modifier</Button>
```

**My router:**

```
exports.editclient = function(req, res) {
  var data = {
    Prenom: req.body.Prenom,
    Nom: req.body.Nom,
    FAX: req.body.FAX,
    Telephone: req.body.Telephone,
    Email: req.body.Email,
    Adresse1: req.body.Adresse1,
    Adresse2: req.body.Adresse2,
  };
  var Code = req.params.Code
  console.log(req.params);
  // var Code = data.Code
  connection.query("UPDATE clients set ? WHERE Code = ? ", [data, req.params.Code], function(error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    else {
      res.send(JSON.stringify(results));
      console.log("Data is updated");
    }
  });
};
```

**My server:**

```
router.put('/editclient/:Code', clients.editclient);
```

I run the backend with Postman with URL  `http://localhost:4000/app/editclient/2222` it works well, but when I run the frontend, the data are not updated and I get :

[image]

How can I fix that ?

Comment: try removing  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"  , because the server is suppose to specify this access not the client...

Comment: @mikkelrd the port 3000 is affected to ReactJS and 4000 to NodeJs.

Comment: @KpTheConstructor I removed it, but I get the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to overcome the CORS issue in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43462367/how-to-overcome-the-cors-issue-in-reactjs)

Comment: I resolve it, to add `:Code` on my route `{ path: '/clients/editclient/:Code', name: 'EditClient', component: EditClient }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is not enabled for the `localhost:4000` server you're trying to access. That's why it doesn't work.

On the other hand, it works with Postman, because Postman it's a dev tool, not a browser. Therefore, it doesn't get affected by CORS not being enabled.

Here's the [easiest way to enable CORS support to your server, if you use Express for NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21622564/1333836).

> Use the node.js package [cors](https://npmjs.org/package/cors). The
>   simplest usage is:
>
> ```
> var cors = require('cors')
>
> var app = express()
> app.use(cors())
> ```

Comment: Thanks @Kaloyan I resolve it, to add cors and `:Code` on my route `{ path: '/clients/editclient/:Code', name: 'EditClient', component: EditClient }`