# Unable to authorize while making api call using fetch

Tags: reactjs

react code to fetch api data

```
    getData = () => {
        const url = FormatUrl(`/cluster`)
        fetch(url,  { 
        method: 'GET', 
        headers: new Headers({
            'Authorization': 'Basic my_token', 
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    })})
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res, "=")
        })
    }
```

error:

```
    Access to fetch at 'https://beta.cnox.io:3001/cluster' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
    beta.cnox.io:3001/cluster:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

Here i am trying to fetch data from above api and sending token also but getting below error. Same api is working from angular.
please take a look

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to overcome the CORS issue in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43462367/how-to-overcome-the-cors-issue-in-reactjs)

Comment: No. Its nothing about backend. Its frontend issue

Comment: It is a *CORS* issue.

Comment: Same one is working for angular application