# Deploying the frontend(ReactJS) and backend(SpringBoot) build on the Tomcat server

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, ubuntu, tomcat

I have deployed the frontend (ReactJS) and backend build(war) on the Tomcat server in the ubuntu machine.
I copied both build in /var/lib/tomcat/webapps folder.
In ReactJS source code I have added

Pckage.json: "homepage": "http://localhost:8080/buildFolderName"

Index.js: axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://**serverUrl**/warfilename/api/'

For this configuration, my application is working fine.

But when we are replacing the **serverUrl** to **localhost:8080** the frontend application is not communicating with the backend APIs.

Showing the error on the browser console: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

We want to deploy the same build on a deferent tomcat server rather than creating a build for each server

Comment: probably a CORS issue, can you open developer tools in your browser and post here logs? If this is indeed a CORS issue, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43462367/how-to-overcome-the-cors-issue-in-reactjs

Comment: On Chrom:         xhr.js:177 POST http://localhost:8080/MyApp/api/auth/signin net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
(anonymous) @ xhr.js:177
e.exports @ xhr.js:13
e.exports @ dispatchRequest.js:50
Promise.then (async)
l.request @ Axios.js:61
r.forEach.l.<computed> @ Axios.js:87
(anonymous) @ bind.js:9
T @ authservice.js:5
(anonymous) @ authentication.js:5
(anonymous) @ index.js:8
onClick @ LoginForm.js:79
Ue @ react-dom.production.min.js:52
Xe @ react-dom.production.min.js:52
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:53
Sr @ react-dom.production.min.js:100

Comment: On Firefox:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/MyApp/api/dashboard/dashboardlog. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
2
Uncaught (in promise) undefined

Comment: It is a CORS issue, you'll have to configure your server application.