# @firebase/firestore: Firestore (8.6.2): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend (React Js)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to connect my react js application with Firebase Firestore but I'm getting the below error as shown in the image [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMPqY.png) I'm having 2 documents in the collection but I'm getting an empty array as you can see in the console. This is the code I'm using to fetch firestore data

```
const snapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('users').get();
const data = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
console.log(data);
```

PS: I'm able to use auth function from firebase properly but getting an error with firestore.

Solutions I have tried so far:

1. Sync the clock
2. verified the firebase rules and made sure read and write are allowed (attaching the rules I found in firestore rules section)

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if 
          request.time < timestamp.date(2021, 6, 23);     
    }
  }
}
```

Looking for some quick solutions as I'm struggling since last night. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following steps to confirm that there is a problem with the react application or browser and fixed the issue.

- Tried to get data and post data to firestore using node and express
  script (this helped to find out that the issue was not with firebase
  configuration)
- After some online research I tried to change my browser from Brave to
  Chrome which actually worked.

Comment: I noticed that there was an extra slash ('/') that got attached to the project Id variable which was stored in the .env file and because of that firebase couldn't fetch the project id.

Answer (score 0):

The First error in your screenshot hints at this actually being a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` CORS issue. So in order to fix it as you can see in [this article](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/dealing-with-cors-in-create-react-app), you can either:

- Add the `"proxy": "http://localhost:PORT_YOU_ARE_USING"` option to your `package.json` file;

or

- Use a middleware like http-proxy-middleware to proxy requests, you can follow the example in the article for that.

Also you can take a look at this [community question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43462367/how-to-overcome-the-cors-issue-in-reactjs), which poses a simillar issue to yours and provide some other solutions. You may get a better understanding of cors issues in React by checking it out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm already having the cors plugin enabled in my browser. I recently observed in the screenshot that the timestamp mentioned there and my system's time are not in sync. Is the issue because of that?

Comment: Isn't it just a timezone difference? I don't think this is the cause of the issue, but you can test it by removing `request.time` rule temporaly.

Comment: Sorry, I just tried that and it didn't help me.

Comment: I don't understand why auth function is working properly and doesn't show any CORS error but firestore is giving me CORS error even though they are in the same app.

Comment: I don't think Auth does any cors check, that is why, but back to your first comment, what do you mean with `I'm already having the cors plugin enabled in my browser`? Did you try to apply in the request themselves like mentioned in my answer? I think there is a difference there.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, I still can't figure out the issue but the issue got **fixed** when I started using Chrome browser instead of Brave browser which I generally use.

Comment: the issue is definitely not CORS as I'm already using another third-party API service in my application.