# Redux Action fetching from backend port

Tags: javascript, node.js, redux, localhost, fetch-api

My app is running on port 3000. and i want to fetch data in a redux action from backend running on port 5000.

The data is not being fetched from backend. I'm getting not defined error.

frontend/redux/categoryAction.js:

```
export const listCategories = () => async (dispatch) => {
try {
    dispatch({ type: 'CATEGORY_LIST_REQUEST' })

    const { data } = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/categories')

    dispatch({
        type: 'CATEGORY_LIST_SUCCESS',
        payload: data
    })
} catch (error) {
    dispatch({
        type: 'CATEGORY_LIST_FAIL',
        payload: error.response && error.response.data.message
            ? error.response.data.message : error.message
    })
 }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to overcome the CORS issue in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43462367/how-to-overcome-the-cors-issue-in-reactjs) the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64178626/1641941) is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You probably get a cors error when you look at the network tab or console.

You should set up a [proxy](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) in your package.json and use a root relative url to the api:

```
fetch('/api/categories')
```

I assume that when this goes into production the api and react files are served on the same domain, if it's not then you can [set up your own proxy](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually)