# 404 when trying to POST request

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm making a web app and it has a login page.
Every time I submit the login credentials I keep getting this error.

> POST http://localhost:3000/api/user/login 404 (Not Found)

Everything works fine on postman.

My userActions.js

```
export const login = (email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
try{
    dispatch({type: USER_LOGIN_REQUEST})

    const config = {
        header: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
    }

    const {data} = await axios.post('/api/user/login',
    { email, password},
    config)
    dispatch({type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: data})

    localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(data))
} catch (error) {
    dispatch({
        type: USER_LOGIN_FAIL,
        payload: error.response && error.response.data.message ?
        error.response.data.message : error.message,
    })
}
}
```

My react app is running on PORT 8675

POST http://localhost:8675/api/user/login in Postman works fine

POST on port 3000 in postman doesn't work however

Comment: You're sending the request to port 3000 in the app, but with Postman you're calling port 8675. I guess that's it?

Comment: So how do I get it to work on the app?

Comment: I can only guess here, but I suppose your app is running on port 3000, right? When you define the endpoint axios should call, you need to specify localhost:8675/api/user/login

Comment: blocked by CORS policy

Comment: Thst's a good sign, now you're not getting a 404 anymore. 

This answer should help you solve the CORS issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43462367/how-to-overcome-the-cors-issue-in-reactjs

Answer (score 0):

You need to write true link on `axios.post("...)`

```
    const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8675/';
    const {data} = await axios.post(baseUrl +'api/user/login',...}

    // or 

    const {data} = await axios.post('http://localhost:8675/api/user/login',...}
```