# CORS headers missing when using Axios in NextJS

Tags: axios, next.js, cors, nestjs

I'm using a NestJS backend with a NextJS frontend, both hosted seperately.

**NestJS Backend**

I enabled CORS in the backend as follows:

```
app.enableCors({ credentials: true, origin: process.env.FRONTEND_URL });
```

When using [cors-test.codehappy.dev](https://cors-test.codehappy.dev/) to check the CORS headers everything looks good. All headers are present and the `access-control-allow-origin` header points to the right domain where the front-end is hosted on.
[image: CORS header response test]

**NextJS Frontend**

On the NextJS frontend I'm using Axios to make request to the backend (the exact same url as used above).However, when creating a request the preflight request in Chrome is missing all CORS headers. The Axios instance below is imported when a HTTP request is needed.

```
import Axios from 'axios';

const api = Axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.BACKENDURL,
    withCredentials: true
});

export default api;
```

The error in the console:
[image: CORS error log in browser]

The preflight request:
[image]

Comment: Is the process.env.FRONTEND_URL contains the exact PORT ?
print that variable to see process.env.FRONTEND_URL exsits.

Comment: @Shachar297, Yes it does, when testing the backend on [cors-test.codehappy.dev](https://cors-test.codehappy.dev) it also shows the right URL in the access-control-allow-origin header.

Comment: Got it, could you take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43462367/how-to-overcome-the-cors-issue-in-reactjs)

Comment: Whatever you use for testing (https://cors-test.codehappy.dev/ or anything else), you need to test with an `OPTIONS` request, because that’s what’s failing: the CORS preflight OPTIONS request. And the preflight is failing because — although the response includes other access-control-allow-\* headers — it doesn’t include the most important one, the access-control-allow-origin header. So however you have the CORS config set up on that server, you need to ensure it’s sending the access-control-allow-origin response header for OPTIONS responses — not just for GET/POST responses.

Answer (score -1):

in `next.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
//avoiding CORS error, more here: https://vercel.com/support/articles/how-to-enable-cors
    async headers() {
        return [
          {
            // matching all API routes
            source: "/api/:path*",
            headers: [
              { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true" },
              { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "*" },
              { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", value: "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT" },
              { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", value: "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version" },
            ]
          }
        ]
    },
}
```

Comment: OP is using a NestJS API, CORS needs to be configured there, not in Next.js.