# CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', I'm using react to get an image url from an api

Tags: reactjs, cors

I'm using react to create a color palette based on Yu Gi Oh! cards but when I get the url I try to turn it into a blob object. But when I request the image I keep getting the error mentioned in the title.

I know it's a problem with the CORS to ensure the safety of the requests coming in. But most of the solution I looked up assume that I'm making a request from React to my server.

I also tried the Chrome Extension Allow Cors and it works but that's just for testing. It wont work when I deploy the website.

Here is the code that I think generates the problem:

```
    const getPalette = async (source) => {
        const file = await fetch(source).then(r => r.blob());
        const fr = new FileReader();

        fr.readAsDataURL(file);

        fr.onload = () => {
            const img = new Image();

            img.src = fr.result;
            img.onload = () => {
                const colorThief = new ColorThief();
                const colorPalette = colorThief.getPalette(img, 9, 10);

                const newPalette = colorPalette.map((color) => {
                    const hex = `#${toHex(color[0])}${toHex(color[1])}${toHex(color[2])}`;
                    return hex;
                });

                setPalette(newPalette);

            };
        };

    };
```

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#what_requests_use_cors: _What requests use CORS? [...] Images/video frames drawn to a canvas using `drawImage()`._ Either make the request same-origin, or configure CORS on the server that serves the image (if you control that server).

Comment: Fixed by following this thread:
[how to overcome the cors issue in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43462367/how-to-overcome-the-cors-issue-in-reactjs?rq=3)

Comment: If you have the time, I highly recommend reading through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/3982562) to get a better understanding of what CORS are, why they exist, and how to work with them. To simply solve your problem, make a request to your own server, with the external URL provided (via URL encoded query parameter, POST body, or any other means). Let your server make the request to the external URL and return the data to your client.

Answer (score 0):

CORS is policy for browsing protection.

So if you want to call this API from your site (aka Origin), it must be allowed at backend (of this API).

Be careful when disable CORS policy in browser (should not do it).

Sometime it shows CORS when your url is wrong. Check the url again.